# SQL Loop through months

Tags: sql, loops

I am very new and know very basic SQL thus I have this question hoping someone can help me out.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) AS Paid, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Count) AS total_Count,
    SUM(Amount) / COUNT(DISTINCT Count) AS Ratio
FROM 
    TableA
WHERE
    Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-30'
```

My question is how can I loop though month by month instead of hard code the date range every time. The goal is to have a final result like this.

```
Month      Paid     Total      Ratio
--------------------------------------
Jan
Feb
Mar
```

Comment: What datatype is the `Date` column? Which DMBS are you using?

Comment: It is a datetime

Comment: You are not looping through anything. When working with SQL, get used to thinking in result set and set based operations. You are not going through row by row and doing things.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention the RDBMS you're using, but they all have a mechanism for extracting the month name from a date.

So, you might do something like

```
SELECT 
datepart(date, 'Month') as month,
sum(Amount) as Paid, 
count(distinct Count) as total_Count,
sum(Amount) / count(distinct Count) as Ratio
FROM TableA
group by datepart(date, 'Month')
```

The "group by" function groups your sum/count columns (in this case by month). You may need to limit dates to the current year, or include a year column.